# Using Node Limit, Show Role How Many Nodes They Can Still Add

Tags: views, nodes

Using Node Limit and have limited roles to be able to add 3, 8 or 20 nodes of one content type depending on what they register with.

I wondered if it's possible to show how many of their limit they have left and then show it on their user page.

So if they have created 3 nodes, they have 5 left (if they had the 8 role allowance).

Comment: by saying "Show Role" , you mean the limitation is for a group or a person? I mean if A who is listed in role X adds a node is it affecting person B who also is a member of role X?

Answer (score 0):

I checked the `node_limit` module and you need to create an `api` to be able to get the remaining limit for a particular `role` or `user`.

1. The number of limit and `limit id` are stored on `node_limit` table.
2. Your `limit id` and `role id` are stored on `node_limit_role` table.

What you need to do next is count the number of nodes the `role` or `user` has created.

Now you need to alter the user profile to print the remaining limit. See the api that you can use [here](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.api.php/7).